# how do I apply validation only if a user has entered in a value?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a signup form where a user enters his main phone, and fax. The fax number is optional, and I'm using the following code in my User.rb model:

```
validates :fax, format: {with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX }, if: :active_or_personal_step?
```

The problem is that this validation kicks in whether the user has entered anything in the field or not. How can I include a "validate only if presence: true" rule into this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validates :fax, format: {with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX}, :unless => 'fax.blank?'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, couple of issues, first it had to be :fax.blank because this is a symbol. But, when I try to run this I get the following error: 


    NoMethodError in UserStepsController#update

    undefined method `validate' for false:FalseClass

Comment: ah, this is working now. I didn't put single-quotes around the 'fax.blank?' Thanks!

Comment: @seth: can you please tell me why it doesnt work for symbol.
Like ive this statement:

`validates :worker_id, presence: true, unless: :team_leader_id.blank?`